# Connect to Azure IOT hub using TCP protocol with ESP8266 No os device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a ESP8266 device with No OS which can communicate using TCP/IP protocol. On Azure I am not able to find a way to connect this device directly to IOT hub. Could you please provide some help or sample code to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT Hub supports MQTT, AMQP, and HTTP.  If you want to use another protocol you need to create a gateway, a middle-man that will bridge the traffic.  Microsoft provides a free one on GitHub.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-protocol-gateway